# Вычислить значение y

Tags: c++

Есть следующий алгортим для рекурсии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Больше ничего не дано. Как рекурсию сделать я понимаю, не понятно только самая нижняя часть алгоритма. В конце мы делим на 1+1/2. Это значит что мы `n` должны делать до тех пор пока оно не будет `n==1`? Откуда тогда 1/2 взялась, это не понятно. Нужна помощь именно для понятия того откуда взялась 1/2.
Исходя из расчетов будет так: `n==3`
y(3)=1/((3-0)+(1/(3-1)+(3-2)+(1/(3-2)))). Возможно где то не закрыл скобку но суть не в этом, суть в том что у нас 1/2 не получается. Или может я что-то не так понимаю?

UPD:

```
    #include <iostream>

double calculateY(double n, double step)
{
    if (n - step == 1.0)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1.0 / (n - step) + calculateY(n, step+1.0);
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::cout << calculateY(5.0, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double calcY(int n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 0.5;
  else
    return 1 / (n + calcY(n - 1));
}
```

Comment: А почему мы при n==0 возвращаем 2?

Comment: @GnomSkull Потому что так написано в самом низу Вашей формулы.